# Consume 2 topics but process only one topic which is enabled

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

For our application we are writing the smae messages to 2 different Kafka Brokers with 2 different topics, now at the consumer part I have to consume both the topics and process only one topic that is enabled in spring boot property file.

How I can do it using spring boot and KafkaListner??

Comment: What exactly do you mean topic is "enabled"? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: You can use the `autoStartup` property of the `@KafkaListener` to control which topic you’d like to consume. That one really can come from external properties configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this simply by :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = { "${spring.kafka.topic1}", "${spring.kafka.topic2}" })
```

Now if you want to consume both but process one and discard the other you can use keys in the messages and create the key accordingly on both topics
Ref:
[Java consumer API](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/package-summary.html) : [ConsumerRecord#key()](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#key--)